# Highlight the label item after clicking on checkbox

Tags: html, css, angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to display the cards as input type is a checkbox, on selecting the cards I am able to fetch the details what are cards selected by the user, and my requirement is I required to highlight the card which is selected by the user.

for example, I need to highlight the card whose checkbox is checked, and if the checkbox is unchecked I need to show as the card.

```css
lable+input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  //some css code
}
```

```html
<form [fromGropu]="form1">

  <label for="{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of items" ;let i=index ">
    <input type="checkbox " id="{{i}} " [value]="item " (change)="onchange() "/>
    
    <div class="card rounded-0 ">
    <div class="card-header ">{{item.header}}</div>
    <diva class="card-body>{{item.desc}}</div>
    <div class="card-footer">{{item.footer}}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </label
    </form>
```

but above CSS is not working, could anyone help on this

Answer (score 1):

After input checked, the div.card following input should apply the css.

Your css should be like this

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div.card{
color: red;
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checked-input?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1):

---

Why not just highlight using a class which is toggled using `ngClass`? please try this change.

```
<form>
    <label for="{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of items;let i =index" (click)="item.active = !item.active;"
  [ngClass]="item.active ? 'active' : ''" style="display:block;">
    <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-header">{{item.header}}</div>
      <div class="card-body">{{item.desc}}</div>
      <div class="card-footer">{{item.footer}}</div>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

Note: please delete this `active` property for the array used if you are sending the data to any API. Below is a working example!

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>